# Order grouped selection by condition in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, web-sql

I have an object store "messages" with "timestamp" and "chat_id" fields inside it. I want to get all "chats" inside this object store ordered by "timestamp" field. As far as I see, I can't do it with IndexedDB only.

I can get them like this using WebDatabase:

```
SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY chat_id ORDER BY timestamp
```

In IndexedDB:

1. if I create compound index using ["chat_id", "timestamp"], records still won't be sorted by "timestamp" field. Instead they will be sorted by "chat_id" first. So that 2-year-old messages with "chat_id" == 1 will be preceding messages with "chat_id" == 2, written yesterday.
2. if I create simple index of "chat_id" and get records from this index using "nextunique", same chat messages are sorted with primary key. In my case it's message "id".

Am I wrong? Is it possible to sort grouped selection in IndexedDB?

UPD: I want to get all chats "grouped" by chat_id and sort this selection by timestamp. So that newest chats will be the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, you want all messages from the chat_id that contains the message with the lowest timestamp first, then all the (as yet unseen) messages from the chat_id that contains a message the next lowest timestamp, etc?

Indexed DB doesn't provide anything specifically helpful here.

A simple approach would use two indexes: one on timestamp, one on chat_id.

1. Let *set* be a new empty Set
2. Open an unbounded cursor on the timestamp index
3. For each *message* seen:

   1. If *message*'s `chat_id` is in *set*

      1. `continue()` the cursor
   2. Otherwise:

      1. add `chat_id` to *set*
      2. open a cursor on the chat_id index with `IDBKeyRange.only(chat_id)` as bounds
      3. fetch all the records

Comment: Yep, I came to the same solution. The only sad thing is that it's working quiet slow if number of records is more than 10k. This is a chrome app.

Comment: A new getAll() method is being added to the Indexed DB standard; Chrome and Firefox should support it in upcoming versions. That would help speed up the fetch by chat_id significantly.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, that's great news! Is it the old firefox-only API which was adopted or something completely new?

Comment: Old FF proposal that was adopted.

Comment: Amazing, I'll add this API into my library: https://github.com/1999/sklad/issues/5

Comment: Seems like getAll is really faster: http://jsperf.com/idb-idbcursor-vs-idbobjectstore-getall-ops/3

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsStore for doing group by, order by or almost all kind of sql queries in indexeddb. It provides api which is identical to sql.

So lets say your query in sql is -

```
SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY chat_id ORDER BY timestamp
```

In JsStore, it will be -

```
var Connection = JsStore.Instance('Db_name');
Connection.select({
     From: 'messages',
     GroupBy:'chat_id',
     Order:{
        By:'timestamp'
     },
     OnSuccess:function(results){
        console.log(results);
     },
     OnError:function(error){
        console.log(error);
     }
})
```

For more check out this link - http://jsstore.net/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to, as you say, sort a grouped selection in indexedDB. But it is not exactly clear from your question what you are asking (at least to me).

Try using ['timestamp','chat_id'] and just use next/prev instead of nextunique/prevunique. You want to order the fields of the index in the order you want to iterate over the cursor. If you want to sort by time, then put timestamp as the first field. In fact this should have the effect of sorting first by time and then by chat id. Of course, this means that you will have messages that arrived around the same time from different chats appearing in separate places.

If the messages with the same chat id must be consecutive, then just use 'next' and cursor.continue, and continue to use ['chat_id','timestamp']. When iterating just check if chat_id changed from the previous iteration to see if a new chat started.

It is not clear why are you using nextunique here. nextunique is just going to iterate over the entire index/store, assuming no two messages with the same chat id can also have the same timestamp. Pretty much every key will be unique in the index, so this would be kinda pointless.

Comment: Hey Josh. Probably I wasn't clear about what "grouping" in my case is. I want to get all chats "grouped" by chat_id and sort this selection by timestamp. So that newest chats will be the first. Using ['timestamp','chat_id'] is not ok, because I will have to get all records fro the object store and group them by myself. As you can see "nextunique" was used to skip same chat messages if key is just "chat_id". Just updated my question.